# Domain Logic - Read Model

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have two aggregates.

```
Person {
    private personID personID;
    private nodeID nodeID; //belongs to node
}
Node {
    private nodeID nodeID; //node's id
    private nodeID parent; //parent node reference by id

    public void assign(Person person);
}
```

Now I have domain logic for my person assigning service: 
Person can be assigned to node `"X"`, only if he belongs to node `"Y"` which is parent or great-grandfather or great-great-grandfather or... of node `"X"`.

To find out it out I would need to query `Read Model`.
I am in Domain so I can't just use my Read Model to query it.
I don't think I can just add to my repository, connection to read model, since it's connected to my event store. Specially, when `Read Model` can be placed at another server and be another application.

What is the proper way to implement it?

Comment: The read model is just an abstraction, you can use it in your domain. CQRS is a _design principle_ of how to model a business use case it's not a rule of having 2 buckets that are separated. In fact CQRS is applied to a bounded context in the sense that parts of the model are used to change business state (command) while others don't change anything (query)

Comment: Okey then. I understand, that read and write are inside the same bounded context. But the problem lays at the technical level. I can't just query Read Model and look there for my aggregates, because such thing like aggregate doesn't exists at that side. Read Model holds denormalized data so I won't be able to build event sourced aggregate from it.  
And what would be responsible for querying read model, repository? Or some abstraction, which in reality would send request to REST API of Read Model?

Comment: You don't use the RM to query aggregates, just to get the data you need for a business decision. My opinion is that your aggregate tries to do too much, you should use it _only_ to change a concept state, not for everything related to a concept. For business queries you have domain services which interpret existing state (the read model) according to business rules. The aggregate's purpose is just to enforce the business constraints which keep the concept valid/consistent, all other behaviour belongs to a domain service.

Comment: So it will be perfectly okey to implement it in this way?
PersonAssigningService -> will protect assigning invariants not related to the aggregate itself and will use PersonAllowedToAssignToNodeStrategy (can't come with better name atm :)), strategy will be interface. Implementation of this strategy will query RM Rest API for necessary information.

Comment: I'd say yes, although querying external services it's a problem. I'd suggest keeping a local RM copy for this purpose.

Comment: What do you mean? The only other way is to go directly to RM database, right? And I don't want to go inside RM database directly, because it serves me an API.

Comment: I mean you should have a read model on that server too, to be used for local querying. So you have one (maybe more specific, tailored) RM on your "command" server and another on the "query" server. Yes, it means RM duplication (really, just use the same library on both servers) but it also mean your servers aren't coupled and performance won't suffer. Call it a trade off.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you very much, you helped me alot :)

Answer (score 2):

The following is a contraint:

> Person can be assigned to node "X", only if he belongs to node "Y"
>   which is parent or great-grandfather or great-great-grandfather or...
>   of node "X".

If it is a constraint that must be enforced, you can model the hierarchy in a separate aggregate on the write side (e.g., `Graph`) whose sole purpose is ensuring integrity.

Comment: Interesting idea. So whenever I add new node or edit existing one I should update the graph, right? But such aggregate would have no logic at all and it purpose would be serving me as Read Model inside domain. Isn't that too much?

Comment: That aggregate is the single source of truth for the hierarchy and not a read model. The consistency logic *is* the logic of that aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to support ancestry checks **in the command model**. This is where you want to enforce the invariant, so the model needs to support this.

Tree structures often lead to performance problem if you need to be able to make unbounded ancestry checks. So you probably need to implement a performance optimization that improves these kinds of queries.

I see the following possibilities:

- Use a data store that directly supports the queries you need. This may be difficult if you want to do ES.
- Use snapshotting. This may or may not be feasible depending on your tree structures.
- Use caching. This is similar to snapshotting, but stores the information in a cache instead of in the event store.
- Use the read model. Be sure you understand the consequences, especially the asynchronous data propagation and the increased complexity. I'd only suggest this as a last resort, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Well in my whole application I have only one place with such kind of logic. So I am not going to move away from my Event Store, because of that. 

To be honest I don't really understand how snapshooting or caching may help in such situation. I would snapshoot/cache single aggregates in domain.
And what I would need to write is recursive query, to find the result I am looking for.